# IE8 error for .play() method

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I wrote some code for playing a .mp3 file on my page. It works on FF and Chrome.

**JS**

```
aSound = document.createElement("audio");
aSound.setAttribute("src", "content/audio/gameIntro.mp3");
aSound.play();
```

However, IE8 displays this error: `Object doesn't support this property or method`     for the 3rd line of code,that is, `aSound.play();`. What can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [IE 8 has no support for the `audio` element.](http://caniuse.com/audio) You can [fall back to Flash](http://html5please.com/#audio) if you want some audio happening on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Only latest version of IE support audio video support as of now. So you need to upgrade you browser to write your HTML5 code.